# Why doesn't it change the data in yajra datatable using Laravel and jQuery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm beginners I have some learning of Laravel and jQuery but I don't know how to update and save the data in yajra datatable. I think there's a missing in my code.

[image]

```
var dataTable = $("#approve_table").DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                url: "{{ route('approve_manual.index') }}"
            },
            columns:[
                // { data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false },
                { data: "view", name: "view", orderable: false },
                { data: "chkbox", name: "chkbox", orderable: false },
                {
                    data: "picture",
                    name: "picture",
                    render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        if (data != '' || data != null) {
                            return (
                                "<img src={{ asset('storage/pictures/') }}/" +
                                data +
                                " loading='lazy' width='30' class='img-thumbnail' />"
                            );
                        } else {
                            return (
                                "<img src={{ asset('storage/pictures/blank.png') }}/" + " width='30' class='img-thumbnail' />"
                            );
                        }
                    },
                    orderable: false
                },
                { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
                { data: 'date', render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment( 'dddd D MMMM YYYY' ) },
                { data: 'category', name: 'category' },
                // { data: 'duration', name: 'duration' },
                { data: "duration",
                    render: function(data, type, row){
                        var strings = row.duration;
                        var temp = strings.split(":")

                        for (let index = 0; index < temp.length; index++) {
                        var hr = temp[0];
                        var mins = temp[1];
                        var sec = temp[2];

                        
                        var zero = hr.charAt(0)
                        var one = hr.charAt(1)
                        var two = mins.charAt(0)
                        var three = mins.charAt(1)

                        
                        if (hr != 00 && mins != 00){
                            var time = hr + ' hr, ' +  mins + ' mins';
                        }
                        else if (hr != 00 && mins == 00){
                            if ( zero == 0 ) {
                                time = one + ' hr ';
                            }
                            else{
                                time = temp[0] + ' hr ';
                            }
                        }
                        else if (hr == 00 && mins != 00){
                            if ( two == 0 ) {
                                time = three + ' mins';
                            }
                            else{
                                time = temp[0] + ' mins';
                            }
                        }
                        else if (hr == 00 && mins == 00 && sec == 00){
                            var time = '1 Day';
                        }
                        return time;
                        }
                    }, 
                },
                { data: "amount",
                render: function(data, type, row){
                    return '₱ ' +  row.amount;
                }, 
                },
            ]
        });
```

```
var id;
        $(document).on("click", ".view", function() {
            id = $(this).attr("id");
            $.ajax({
                url: "/admin/approve_manual/" + id + "/edit",
                dataType: "json",
                error: function (html) {
                    // console.error(html);
               
                },
                success: function(html) {
                    
                    document.getElementById("blah").src = "{{ asset('storage/pictures/') }}" + '/' + html.data[0].picture;
                    $("#approve_id").val(html.data[0].idx);
                    $("#name").text(html.data[0].name);
                    $("#emp_no").val(html.data[0].emp_no);
                    $("#date").val(html.data[0].date);
                    $("#category").val(html.data[0].category);

                    var strings = html.data[0].duration;
                    var temp = strings.split(":");
                    var hr = temp[0];
                    var mins = temp[1];
                    var sec = temp[2];
                    var zero = hr.charAt(0)
                    var one = hr.charAt(1)
                    var two = mins.charAt(0)
                    var three = mins.charAt(1)
                    
                    if (hr != 00 && mins != 00){
                        var time = hr + ' hr, ' +  mins + ' mins';
                    }
                    else if (hr != 00 && mins == 00){
                        if ( zero == 0 ) {
                            time = one + ' hr ';
                        }
                        else{
                            time = temp[0] + ' hr ';
                        }
                    }
                    else if (hr == 00 && mins != 00){
                        if ( two == 0 ) {
                            time = three + ' mins';
                        }
                        else{
                            time = temp[0] + ' mins';
                        }
                    }
                    else if (hr == 00 && mins == 00 && sec == 00){
                        var time = '1 Day';
                    }
                    $("#duration").val( time );

                    // $("#duration").val(html.data[0].duration);
                    $("#amount").val(html.data[0].amount);
                    

                    $("#approve_modal").modal("show");
                }
            });
        });
```

```
const save = (status, id_list) => {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('approve_manual.store') }}",
                data: {
                    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                    id : id_list,
                    status : status
                },
                method: "POST",
                error: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    // console.log(data);
                    
                    var html = "";
                    if (data.errors) {
                        error(data.errors);
                    }
                    if (data.payroll) {
                        check_payroll();
                        $("#approve_modal").modal("hide");
                        document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
                    }
                    if (data.success) {
                      
                        dataTable.ajax.reload(null, false);
                        document.getElementById("approve_for_many").removeAttribute("disabled");
                        document.getElementById("unapprove_for_many").removeAttribute("disabled");
                        document.getElementById("approve_each").removeAttribute("disabled");
                        document.getElementById("unapprove_each").removeAttribute("disabled");
                        document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
                        success(data.success);
                        $("#approve_modal").modal("hide");
                    }
                    $('input#checkAll2').prop('checked', false);
                    $('input#checkbox_id').prop('checked', false);
                    chkbox = []; 
                }
            });
        }

           
        });
```

And here is the code I added.

```
 dataTable.draw();
```

```
if (data.success) {
                      
                        dataTable.ajax.reload(null, false);
                        document.getElementById("approve_for_many").removeAttribute("disabled");
                        document.getElementById("unapprove_for_many").removeAttribute("disabled");
                        document.getElementById("approve_each").removeAttribute("disabled");
                        document.getElementById("unapprove_each").removeAttribute("disabled");
                        document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
                        success(data.success);
                        $("#approve_modal").modal("hide");
                    }
                    $('input#checkAll2').prop('checked', false);
                    $('input#checkbox_id').prop('checked', false);
                    chkbox = []; 
                    dataTable.draw();
                }
```

But when I click the save Button nothing happened.

Comment: If you open up the browser developer console and look at the network tab... what is the result when you click the save button? If you're unfamiliar with the developer console watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x4q86IjJFag

Comment: {success: 'Success'}success: "Success"[[Prototype]]: Object. @dvicemuse I think it work?

Comment: What happens when you use `dataTable.clear().draw()` or `dataTable.ajax.reload()` instead of `dataTable.ajax.reload(null, false)` and comment out `success(data.success)`

I suspect you are creating a callback conflict

Comment: Nothings happend sir. its the same the text is not changing. @dvicemuse

Comment: Then i suspect your `dataTable` js variable isn't globally defined... so what happens when you use `$("#approve_table").DataTable().ajax.reload()`?

Comment: Can I show you my whole code? and the controller in laravel? @dvicemuse

Comment: Okey sir thanks :) I sent a message sir thanks you can delete your message sir @dvicemuse